# Auto Download & Untar Script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Looking to write a script for my Linux Server so look for a specific folder name, then wget a file, and untar.

Where would I start with this? I know that it has to be written in bash, but I'm very unfamiliar with the language.

Looking to get it to wget into folder `/home/*/public`. The `*` indicating that it doesn't matter what folder, as long as `public` exists.

Comment: Something like `cd /home/*/public && wget http://foo/bar.tar -O - | tar x`? `cd` only uses the first argument, so as long as one such directory exists, the command should work.

Comment: @muru (and for the OP) that's assuming shell expansion on `*` still gives rise to right output directory... otherwise that's a good suggestion.

Comment: @h.j.k. well, since "it doesn't matter what folder as long as public exists', any expanded directory will be the right directory.

Comment: Okay. So I was able to get some of the command down... but now let's say that I want it to be for directories that are newly created. this is what I have so far... `test -d "/root/appname/*/public" || cd "/root/appname/hello/public" && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar xzf latest.tar.gz && mv wordpress/* . && rm latest.tar.gz && rmdir wordpress` ........ so the point of this is to download wordpress, and extract it when a new folder from `/home/[THIS FOLDER IS CREATED VIA WEB INTERFACE]/public` is created. of course, I'd only want it for new directories –

Answer (score 0):

This script will download `bar.tar` file in every "public" directory in `/home/*/`

```
#!/bin/bash
base="$PWD"

for dir in /home/*/public/
do
    cd ${dir}
    wget http://foo/bar.tar -O - | tar x
    cd ${base}
done
```

Of course that can be done in many different ways, but this seems easiest to understand.

Comment: Would this script work for only newly created folders in the home folder? I would like that.

Also, I'd like to adjust it to download & extract wordpress' latest.tar.gz into public.